# How do you add a user in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs

I've set up TFS 2012 on a server and am trying to add a user to the *Project Collection Valid Users* group. I'm trying to do this through the web interface.

[image: Add A Windows User or Group dialog]

When I hit **Save Changes** it errors with `TF50618: The Team Foundation Valid Users group cannot be modified directly.`

[image: TFS Error]

What I am trying to do is get one user set up on TFS so that I can connect Visual Studio 2012 to it. I do not have any projects set up yet. My intention is to import a VSS repository into TFS.

Comment: since you are still using VSS, go with GIT and GitHub.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd go with Mercurial or Subversion. But... it is not up to me.

Comment: You can see this link http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-do-you-add-user-in-tfs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `Project Collection Valid Users` to be a read only group. The members of that group are determined by the members of the child-groups. If you want to have another person in that group, try adding them to one of the groups within the scope. As it sounds like an administrative task you are about to do, add your user to the `Project Collection Administrators Group`.

Later, you are assigning new users to the `Team Projects` of the `Default Collection`. The Team Projects are automatically assigned to the `Project Collection Valid Users Group`.